# When total time gets minimized?

Tags: trigonometry

We want to get from $\displaystyle{C}$ to $\displaystyle{A}$.

The path $\displaystyle{C \to B \to D \to A}$ can be done with constant velocty $\displaystyle{w}$.

So that the time to get there gets minimized, we prefer the path $\displaystyle{C \to D \to A}$.

At the part $\displaystyle{CD}$ we move with constant velocity $\displaystyle{u}$ with $\displaystyle{u < w}$.

Show that the total time $\displaystyle{T}$ gets minimized when $\displaystyle{\sin t = \frac{{Ru}}{{(k + R)w}}}$.

[image]

Do you have any hints?

P.S. Sorry for the picture, I don't know any good program to draw such forms. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: Assuming $\omega$ as angular velocity, correct if wrong**

**Anyways change $\frac{\pi-\alpha}\omega$ to $\frac{R(\pi-\alpha)}\omega$ if referring $\omega$ as speed**

Let $\angle OCD=t$ and $\angle BOD=\alpha$
Now use sine rule to get:
$$\frac{R}{\sin t}=\frac{CD}{\sin\alpha}$$
So: $$CD=R\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin t}$$
And $\arc DA=R(\pi-\alpha)$
Now time is:
$$t=\frac1uR\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin t}+\frac{\pi-\alpha}{\omega}$$
Now differentiate it and find minima.

Comment: Since the path from $C$ to $B$ was also to be done at speed $w,$ I think this really was meant to be linear velocity and not angular velocity. But then you can substitute $R/w$ for $1/\omega$, as you say.

Comment: @DavidK I too was sure but didn't rejected that possibility until OP's clarification because of two reasons: $\omega$ is common for angular velocity, secondly the word "velocity" and "speed" may be same to mathematicians, it is different to physicists.

Comment: Good point, physically you can't travel the arc from $B$ to $A$ at constant _linear_ velocity. I would prefer that the problem just said $w$ was a _speed_ so that there is not this ambiguity.

Comment: @DavidK thanks.